# Instantiate a QQuickView within a QDialog Window

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm converting from qt4 to qt5.
I had the following code:

mpDV = new QDeclarativeView(QDialog*);

... which worked perfectly.

I can't do this with QQuickView because it expects a QWindow* as argument.

Is there a quick work-around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for posting, found an answer: There is a new function (tagged preliminary) called QWidget::windowHandle(), which does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use QWidget::createWindowContainer.